# How do I subtract two entire columns and have the difference show in a new column?

Tags: excel, vba, range, subtraction

Column H has values from H2 to H979, Column I has values from I2 to I979. I want to subtract I from H all the way down the sheet until row 979 
(ie. H50 - I50) and have the difference appear in column AJ in excel. How do I code this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Also you could use a simple formula in AJ: `=H2-I2` and drag that down. (See John's Answer)

Comment: So far I have tried recording the macro (bottom left corner of excel) and it looks like this:Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-RC[-1]"
    Range("C2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C979"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("C2:C979").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15
End Sub

Comment: Don't leave code in the comments, [edit] your question to include it. Also why do you want to use a macro?

Answer (score 1):

In `AJ2` place the following formula:

```
= H2-I2
```

Then drag it down until the last row (979).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Sub Minus()
    [AJ2:AJ979] = [H2:H979-I2:I979]
End Sub
```